# FBConnect "via" link broken on feed posts from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink, feed, fbconnect

I have an iOS app that is successfully posting to Facebook via the FBConnect SDK. I have registered the app in Facebook as a native iPhone app and filled out the required data (bundle ID, app store id, etc), however I am running into one small, but very annoying issue.

When the app posts to the user's feed, the message has a "via App Name" link that presumably goes to the app store, or somewhere sensible. This link never work, it always goes to a page stating "Page not found", with no helpful information.

The link is of the form: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=${app.id}

I have verified that the ID that it is putting in there is in fact my app ID. Can anyone shed some light on what might be causing this and some possible fixes?